# Linux and RTOS using SoC (ARM, Xilinx)

Tags: linux, real-time, fpga, rtos

I am facing a design "issue". I have a board with Xilinx Zynq Soc including dual-core ARM9 and I need to develop an application to support real-time property control application (time deadlines to response time) and also application to do heavy processing (image etc.) and some basic communications between them, but most importantly I will need to be able to control the Linux part (at least e.g. to somehow suspend it, "pause it" in best case to have possibility to shut it down and then run it again). So I was wondering how to combine it.

One of the option, could be RTLinux, which at least to description, what I found offers possibility to run realtime kernel and linux kernel next to it as a thread but it seems that it is now proprieatary by WindRiver..

Then I stepped up over MicroBlaze, where it could be possible to "create" soft processor on Programmable logic, but I am not sure if I can run RTOS on ARM and Linux there?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that seem to be known as rtlinux.   The one you mention, a Wind River revival of the MERT system is a product of that company.  Another one, seemingly “RT Linux”, is a real time patch to the mainline kernel which provides deterministic scheduling and fine grained kernel pre-emption.

I think it is the latter one that you want.   10s of google indicates that there is a kconfig target for this SoC, so all the pieces you need should be there.

Do remember there is more to a real time system than just the ability to be real time; the subsystems also have to be well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, you have (at least) the following design options:

1. Dual kernel approach: this means patching the Linux kernel with a (quite invasive) patch that runs a tiny real-time kernel alongside the standard kernel. This approach allows reaching good real-time performance (even in the order of us) at the cost of complexity. It was implemented by the [RTLinux project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux) (acquired and then discontinued by Windriver), then by [RTAI](https://www.rtai.org/) (mostly focusing on x86) and [Xenomai](https://xenomai.org/).
   If you go along this path, you can see if Xenomai supports your specific SoC; then patch, configure and rebuild the kernel; and finally write the real-time code following Xenomai's API.
2. Improving the responsiveness of the Linux standard kernel: this is what the [PREEMPT_RT project](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start) aims at. The real-time performance is lower with respect to the previous approach, but you don't have to write real-time specific code. With this approach, you can patch and build the kernel, then see if the real-time performance is sufficient for your needs.
3. Synthesizing a Microblaze soft-core on the FPGA, then run Linux on the ARM cores and the real-time code ((either bare-metal or with an RTOS) on the Microblaze.

Unfortunately, your specific SoC does not support ARM's virtualization extensions. Otherwise there would be the additional option of Multi-OS approach: running the Linux OS on one ARM core and the real-time code (either bare-metal or with an RTOS like [ERIKA Enterprise](http://www.erika-enterprise.com/)) on the other ARM core, through a hypervisor like [Jailhouse](https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse) or [Xen](https://xenproject.org/).